# Save images in phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, dreamweaver, web-sql

Hi I have to develop an application that consists of the world cup fifa stamp album.
I have all the stamps in a png format, so in the first module i need to show the stamps that i own and the ones that not.
My original idea was to store in a database an entity called stamp that includes the image, the name of the player, the id of the stamp and the quantity that i own of each one.  I don´t know which storage option to use i know that localstorage can´t store the images so I think my only option is web sql.
Is this the correct approach or the other one is to save the images like in a local folder and then using local storage save the path to the image, the id, name and number of the stamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your life will be easier if you would store the images in the file system and their locations in the database.

- Images must be served as static files so you will be able to access them directly
- You don't need additional code to extract and stream the images
- Images are easy to cache and store on the file system
- The database also stores the data on the file system
- For a web app you would could use multiple servers to improve performance

So yes, save the images in a local folder and use localstorage or web database to save the image paths.

Answer (score 0):

For storing large amount of data you have to use SQLite for iOS and indexeddb for all other platforms.

There are two ways to access SQLite in phonegap. Either use native websql or sqliteplugin.

You can try out my library which abstract these storage mechanism. See here for example app https://github.com/yathit/cordova-sqliteplugin-todo

For storing image in the database, see [here](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/transaction.html) in "Storing File and Blob data" section.